# Symfony add embedded collection prototype empty string

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I'm probably missing something stupid.  But I'm following this cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and want to have a link/button to add more filters to a brand.  But the `data-prototype` attribute is always empty despite no errors from symfony.

Here's my forms

```
<?php

namespace DB\ScoreboardBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use DB\ScoreboardBundle\Form\Type\FilterType;

class BrandType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name' , 'text' , array('label' => 'Brand Name'))
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('publicKey' , 'text' , array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('privateKey' , 'text' , array('read_only' => true))
            ->add('enabled' , 'checkbox' , array('label' => 'Enabled?' , 'required' => false))
            ->add('filters' , 'collection' , array(
                'type' => new FilterType(),
                'allow_add' => true));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DB\ScoreboardBundle\Entity\Brand',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'brand';
    }
}
```

Filters

```
<?php

namespace DB\ScoreboardBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('field' , 'text')
            ->add('value', 'text')
            ->add('operator' , 'choice' , array('choices' => array(
                '=' => 'Equals (=)',
                '>=' => 'Greater than / equals (>=)',
                '<=' => 'Less than / equals (<=)',
                '>' => 'Greater than (>)',
                '<' => 'Less than (<)'
            )))
            ->add('enabled' , 'checkbox' , array('label' => 'Enabled?' , 'required' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'DB\ScoreboardBundle\Entity\Filter',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'filter';
    }
}
```

Here's my controller.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use DB\ScoreboardBundle\Entity\Brand;
use DB\ScoreboardBundle\Entity\BrandManager;
use DB\ScoreboardBundle\Form\Type\BrandType;

class BrandController extends Controller
{
    public function viewAction(Brand $brand)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new BrandType() , $brand , array('action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_brand_edit' , array('id' => $brand->getId()))))
            ->add('save' , 'submit')
            ->add('new_keys' , 'submit' , array('label' => 'Save with New Keys'));

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Brand:view.html.twig' , array('brand_form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

And here's the view

```
{% block content %}
    <div id="add-admin" class="container">

        <div class="panel col-md-8">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Brand</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {% if brand_form is defined %}
                    {{ form_start(brand_form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(brand_form)}}
                    <ul class="filters" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(brand_form.filters.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                    </ul>
                    {{ form_end(brand_form) }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

But in the end `data-prototype` is always empty when I do an inspect element.  If I do a `{{ dump(brand_form) }}` I can see that the filters content exists.  So what little detail am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  Didn't read this part.

> If you render your whole "tags" sub-form at once (e.g.
>   form_row(form.tags)), then the prototype is automatically available on
>   the outer div as the data-prototype attribute, similar to what you see
>   above.

So since I was rendering the form as a whole, it already was generating the prototype and apparently symfony prevents it from double rendering.

Comment: Hey how do you handle the prototype rendering after form submission? I am facing a problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46790530/customizing-data-prototype-symfony3