# Customizing data prototype symfony3

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, symfony

I have an embedded collection of forms, with custom data-prototype attribute. Here is how I am customizing the data-prototype

My main twig file(`listingbedroomaddpage.html.twig`):

```
<div class="bedrooms" data-prototype=
        "{% filter escape %}
             {{ include('EpitaHousingBundle:Listing:prototype.html.twig', { 'form': form.bedrooms.vars.prototype }) }}
         {% endfilter %}">
            </div>
```

My `prototype.html.twig`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_label(form.rentamount, 'Rent') }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_widget(form.rentamount) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_widget(form.rentcurrency) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_widget(form.rentduration) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{ form_errors(form.rentamount) }}</div>  
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_errors(form.rentcurrency) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_errors(form.rentduration) }}</div>
</div>
```

When I render the form for the first time the `prototype.html.twig` is called and the embedded form is rendered correctly. However once I submit the form, The embedded form's twig structure and styling is gone. Here are the snapshots before and after submit respectively

[image]

[image]

My guess is that the prototype.html.twig does not get called after submit is clicked. I am relatively new to this. Can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Going to need to see some more code.  Can you update your post to include the whole `listingbedroomaddpage.html.twig` file.  We'll start with that, but might also need to see your controller as well.

Comment: @Squeegy thanks for the response, But I figured it out. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Mind to ask how did you figure it out?

Comment: you've found a solution
 pliz ?

Comment: @CrownBackend check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sorry for being a little late, but here it is.
In the main twig you need to loop through all the collections(in this case form.bedrooms) and inside the loop render the prototype form. below this code

```
<div class="bedrooms" data-prototype=
    "{% filter escape %}
         {{ include('EpitaHousingBundle:Listing:prototype.html.twig', { 'form': form.bedrooms.vars.prototype }) }}
     {% endfilter %}">
        </div>
```

like this

```
    {% for bedroom in form.bedrooms %}
                            <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_label(bedroom.rentamount, 'Rent') }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_widget(bedroom.rentamount) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_widget(bedroom.rentcurrency) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{{ form_widget(bedroom.rentduration) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">{{ form_errors(bedroom.rentamount) }}</div>  
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_errors(bedroom.rentcurrency) }}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{{ form_errors(bedroom.rentduration) }}</div>
</div>
    {% endfor %}
```